# Choose between which type of WCF proxy generation path we should take?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-endpoint, wcf-proxy

I am new to WCF service. I am aware about three ways to generate proxies.

1. Using Service reference
2. Using SvcUtil
3. Using ClientBase

But I am confused in which case I should use which type. In my case I have to generate proxies for third party service for which I don't have service code. I don't want to use add service reference because it gives me following issue. Mentioned in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340931/using-common-service-reference-assembly-in-different-client-application-gives-er). So I want to use clientBase. But I think I cannot use it without using service reference. I am pretty much confused when should we choose which kind of proxies.

Comment: Well don't add service references to your library projects, only your applications

Comment: In that case I have to add service reference at multiple places as I will have multiple apps using this service. I don't think its good way.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

> In my case I have to generate proxies for third party service for which I don't have service code.
>
> I will have multiple apps using this service.

In that case you are better off using **SvcUtil** because it can generate a single library that *all* of your projects can use, even if they are .NET libraries.   After it is generated you can always go in and tweak it.

**Add service reference** on the other hand is fine for a single .exe but as you have discovered, is annoying for multiple apps as you need to repeat the process and you end up with multiple definitions of WCF types that is just going to increase maintenance.

Just be sure to leave WCF client config in the app.config of your applications and not your app.config of your class library (as the former may not be read).

If your vendor had followed *"[WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101)"* it would have made your life easier.

SOAP purists would argue however that the only thing the vendor provides is a SOAP WSDL XML file from which you are required to generate your types anyway.  (sadly, the default behaviour in .NET is back-to-front)

Comment: ClientBase can only be used if I am the owner of service. Is it correct?

Comment: Well, you normally need the service interface type and unless the vendor provides you with it, you just use the one generated during the client proxy generation, which by that time is too late.  You may as well use the established code.   If the vendor is giving you an API in the form of a .NET client library, you can create your own proxy using `ClientBase` with the interface they provide.  But it doesn't sound like they are doing that.  To answer your question, anyone can use `ClientBase` but you need the service contract first

Comment: After proxy generation using Svcutil I am still getting The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'xxx' is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

Comment: @TBAG Interesting.  Why not ask that as a _new question_.  Your question above is more about _best practices_ whereas the latter is more about a _specific problem_